# Арендуемое объект

Tags: склонение

Подскажите, слово "объект" в этом предложении не склоняется?

> Арендуемое ОБЪЕКТ должно быть передано Арендатору не позднее 10
>   (десяти) календарных дней.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это уточнение, написанное в скобках или, например, между длинными тире, то можно не склонять. В других случаях склонять нужно.

Comment: В других случаях склонять нужно, тогда могу начать предложения - Арендуемое ОБЪЕКТЕ?

Comment: @БерикТолен Вы должны написать: "Арендуемый объект должен быть передан". Все слова стоят в мужском роде, единственном числе, именительном падеже. Если же вы пишите "арендуемое", то и существительное у вас должно быть среднего рода, например: "арендуемое имущество".